# Hiding a file or data from being accessed unless on scheduled days

Tags: scheduled-tasks, access-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [restricting access to volumes disk even for admin account windows](https://superuser.com/questions/205934/restricting-access-to-volumes-disk-even-for-admin-account-windows)
>   [How to restrict use of a computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/213885/how-to-restrict-use-of-a-computer)

I want to limit my access to some data and what I want is that I should be able to access the data only on certain days of the month (e.g., every 3rd day).

Is there any way like encryption or some utility to allow me to only access data on specific days?

One idea that I was thinking of was to encrypt the data and store the password (will be complex and long so that I couldn't remember it right away) on some website which would then email me back the password in future on those specific days.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Yes, you got me curious. Why? o.O

Comment: @KronoS: I can't control myself from playing PC games i.e waste lots of time on them which effects my academic performances and so i need solution to this.AND deleting them is no a option(that would be suicidal).

Comment: refer to these: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14625/how-do-i-limit-my-gaming

http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1372/techniques-to-deal-with-game-addiction

http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12620/how-do-i-keep-a-healthy-game-life-balance

Comment: Will you re-encrypt with a different key every time you get the password emailed to you?

Comment: @gkt.pro: downgrade your hardware to get worse gaming experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go with the email option, try [here](http://futureme.org/)

Comment: Are you sure that they won't spam me.

Comment: Prettu sure @gkt.pro else they would be out of business pretty soon

Comment: There is a problem it says :"Send date must be at least 30 days into the future"

Answer (score 1):

If the data is not too large, you may store it on a server which will show it at some times. That needs some coding, though.